# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null in cast_sender.js

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to update my chrome based chromecast app to the official SDK and I'm seeing intermittent initialization failures in cast_sender.js line 3383 with an error of :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null

Usually reloading makes it go away.

Is this a know issue ?

Comment: Are you fully moved to and seeing this issue in the new SDK? Or still on the previous one? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, fully moved to using the new SDK. Loading from https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js

Comment: Seems like this was a bug as the chrome sender app dev page (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) now contains new initialization code. It works consistently now for me